# How to set unique id by row and column to Antd table input fields?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Currently I'm trying to build an input based table

```
    const columns = [{
        title: 'Items',
        dataIndex: `Items`,
        key:`Items`
    }];
```

Then I loop thru an array for the rest of the columns that are for checkbox

```
        countryList.forEach((id) => {
        const data = CountryDetail[id].name;
        columns.push({
            title: data,
            dataIndex: data,
            key: data,
            render: (value, rowId) => (
                <Checkbox 
                    checked={value}
                    ...
            )
        })
    });
```

The datasource will be dynamically generated as well. Since I need to get the boolean values from the checkboxes, is there a way to give all checkbox unique id for identification for submission? I had tried creating with function but since it is in class component, usestate could not be used.

```
const data = [{
   Items: 'Chips',
   Japan: true,
   ...
}]
```

Comment: Can you not use `id` as your unique id? It is a going to be acountry name right?

Comment: @TusharShahi hi sorry maybe I wasn't clear in my question, my current submission is based on input fields id, currently horizontal headers are items, country1, country2... and the vertical 'header' are item1, item2,... so the checkbox ids would be "item1_country1","item1_country2",...

Comment: @Nyxia Hi, what is wrong with these ids for the checkbox cells? `so the checkbox ids would be "item1_country1","item1_country2",...`

Comment: @KevinHaxhi Hi, these ids are for identification when trying to grab value to submit, I'm uncertain how to add the ids to the checkboxes by column and row within antd table